linux sort float numbers starting with point
I would expect that the -g flag tells sort to treat the fields as floating point numbers, but:
cat << EOF | sort -g -k1,2
0 0
0 1.0
0 .5 
0 5.0
EOF

gives
0 0
0 1.0
0 .5 
0 5.0

Therefore the .5 is not treated as a 0.5. Is this a known bug or what?
p.s.: I'm not asking for a workaround, I have already solved with sed

Solved it with sed? You can't sort with sed (well, you can, but sorting using regular expressions is a bit inflexible). If you have added a zero to all entries that start with a dot, using sed, I would call that a workaround.

yes, I have added a zero to all entries that start with a dot, using sed. I agree it's a workaround, as I meant

When you do sort -g -k1,2, the entirety of the text from key 1 to key 2 is taken as a field. So the text that sort attempts to parse is 0 0, 0 1.0, etc., and not 0, 0 separately or 0, 1.0 separately. It has nothing to do with the leading zero (except insofar as it affects lexicographic sorting). You can check this by using other floating point formats. Taking this input, for example:
% cat foo
0 0
0 1.0
0 1.23
0 1.1e-1
0 .5
0 5.0

We get:
% sort -g -k1,2 foo
0 0
0 1.0
0 1.1e-1
0 1.23
0 .5
0 5.0

Clearly it's doing lexicographic sorting on 1.1e-1 and 1.0.
What you want is setting each field as a key separately:
sort -g -k1,1 -k2,2

Or:
sort -k1,1g -k2,2g 

And then we get the expected order:
% sort -g -k1,1 -k2,2 foo
0 0
0 1.1e-1
0 .5
0 1.0
0 1.23
0 5.0

% sort -k1,1g -k2,2g foo
0 0
0 1.1e-1
0 .5
0 1.0
0 1.23
0 5.0

